# How to run a job based on a tag-name

Tags: github, github-actions

I have the following condition:

```
name: Build Image

on:
  push:
  pull_request:
  workflow_dispatch:
    

jobs:

  build-image: (This should be only if the tag contains "azure")
    name: Build Image Job
    runs-on: [ self-hosted ]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Run Build Step
      run: |
        ANSIBLE_VERSION=$(cat VERSION)
        docker images

jobs:

  build-image: (This will be for everything else)
    name: Build Image Job
    runs-on: [ self-hosted ]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Run Build Step
      run: |
        ANSIBLE_VERSION=$(cat VERSION)
        docker images
```

How can that be achieved? How do you reference the tags inside a job?
How do you the variable and make an if rule out of it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use regex in your `on` config to trigger a workflow based on a tag name. For example:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - '*azure*'
```

At the level of a job or a step, you can use a `contains()` expression:

```yaml
jobs:
  build-for-azure-tag:
    name: build-for-azure-tag
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: github.ref_type == 'tag' && contains(github.ref_name, 'azure')
```

Comment: What about locally on a job name

Comment: I updated my answer to include tag-triggering logic at the level of a job.